# Indexical language uses

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

We have language where we derive a name that can denote contextually, but then use it in ways that makes no sense for the objects being discussed.

For example: 'The number of people in the room is five' let's say that people are entering and leaving the room.

The next minute we might say 'The number of people in the room is four'.

It is a fact that 'the number of people in the room' denotes some natural number at any instant.

Yet why do we hear statements like 'the number of people in the room is changing'

No matter what statement, a natural number does not change it is but itself.

Say for example that 'The number of people in the room is seven' is a true statement, then 'The number of people in the room is changing' is equivalent to 'seven is changing' which is meaningless.

Why can we use this? It is often done in other situations like physics and engineering where 'the water level' both denotes a inanimate mathematical object and also is described as 'changing'

Comment: See [The temperature is ninety and rising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_paradox)

Comment: You can find a sketch of Richard Montague's solution to the problem in https://www.ling.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Oeffentliche_Medien/Fakultaeten/Philosophische_Fakultaet/Sprache_und_Information/Allgemeine_Sprachwissenschaft/Dateien/Sebastian_Loebner/Loebner_Partee_Paradox_in_Semantic_Companion.pdf.

Comment: "The number of people in the room", in the change context, is the (compound) name of a value of the function of time, not of a fixed number. And it makes perfect sense that it changes. We use names disambiguated by context to avoid unnecessary mouthfuls that serve no useful purpose because the context is available. The use in this example is intensional, btw, on top of indexical.

Answer (score 2):

English is not a formal language it is a natural language and works differently. The meaning of words and phrases in natural languages are different depending on context. In your example, "The number of people in the room" clearly refers to the count of people inside the room and not to the mathematically formal entity that is a natural number. Such distinctions are the reasons that formal languages needed to be created to ensure that we can have error free communication and strict proofs.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: So in your opinion, it is not strictly logical, however it becomes difficult to say to someone that 'the string "the number of people in the room" denotes a different number whenever anyone enters or leaves" so to do it this way is consise and easy to understand due to convention more than anything?

Comment: It is not logical because natural languages are much older than logic.

Comment: English is not natural language(mostly) it had set up at XVI century.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Let's look at philosophy of language being developed by modern philosophers of language. According to linguistics and the language of philosophy, pragmatics dictates that every conversation occurs within a [linguistic context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_(language_use)) where there is a shared frame of reference. Some of the information that is in the context is what is called [deictic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis). Generally, according to the Cooperative Principle formulated by the Oxfordian Grice, there are certain implicit rules in conversation including the [Maxim of Quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle#Maxim_of_quantity_(content_length_and_depth)) that has some subrules:

> Submaxims: ... Make your contribution as informative as is required (for the current purposes of the exchange)... Do not make your contribution more informative than is required.

Thus, we can paraphrase your conversation thusly:

> *S1* The number of people in the room is four (at time t<sub>1</sub>).
> *S2* The number of people in the room is five (at time t<sub>2</sub>).
> *S3* The number of people in the room is six (at time t<sub>3</sub>).
> *S4* The number of people in the room keeps changing (that is to say varying over time).

Where did the information come from? The information implicit in the communication for S1-S3 comes from deixis regarding the spatiotemporal presumption that is built into the communication. Resolving the sense of 'changing' emerges from [frame semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_semantics_(linguistics)) which is built into any public language. Since communication is an act of [collective intentionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_intentionality), if any hearer is confused, they simply can ask a question to elicit different information to clarify the deixis and frame semantics that inheres to the conversation, that is, they clarify the linguistic context. The [temperature paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_paradox) is thus dissolved by examining the pragmatics instead of direct appeals to truth-conditions. In the philosophy of language, there was a period before these pragmatic notions were accepted by philosophers, but contemporary linguists and philosophers of language believe that the pragmatics of Strawson, Grice, and other ordinary language philosophers helps explain how Fregean and Traskian truth-semantics is an incomplete picture of a theory of meaning, semantics. In fact, [there are a number of theories of semantics that build on older theories of truth-conditional and use-theory theories of semantics such as cognitive semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics#Disciplines_and_paradigms_in_linguistic_semantics).

EDIT RE OP'S COMMENT

No, not a "pragmatic use of language". [Pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics). It's a subdiscipline of linguistics. Not all meaning is logical, and the formal predicate logic you're working with is a syntactical model or abstraction of the reason we conduct psychologically. Is it not quite logical? Well, if logic is scoped to include the act of predication, then context is merely implicit predication, that is, it's there, but not stated. That doesn't make it illogical, just presumed.

What you need to understand is that formal logic is just an abstraction of language, a model, a word-game if you will. It's designed, an artifact, artificial. Language is constructed and used by people as tools. You can write NumberInRoom(4) and NumberInRoom(5), or NumberInRoom(4,t<sub>1</sub>) and NumberInRoom(5,t<sub>2</sub>) and then you can choose from the rules of logic. Don't like Law of the Excluded Middle? Fine! Don't use it.

You absolutely can use a variable expression to model what you've described. NumberInRoom(N,t) where N := {4,5,6} and t := {1,2,3}. Now your domains of discourse are N and t, defined [extensionally (by a list of values) with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_(predicate_logic)) integer values respectively. You can define it intensionally as t:= {n>10 for n in Z} Or you can create relations with tuples. NumberInRoom(N,R+) with the N above and R being all positive, real numbers.

Natural numbers are just a way of labeling a sequence. In fact, a sequence is often defined as any set in which there's a one-to-one correspondence with the naturals. They're just a label for things that are ordered. They're always unique in that any number is essentially a successor of another, and that there is a special number, the number 1 which has no successor.

Comment: Based on this, would you say, to describe it this way is a pragmatic use of language, if somehwat logically flawed? It is not unlike 'variables' if I have a formula and a free variable ranging over some domain, I may say something like 'x varies over the reals' etc.

Comment: I responded at length with an edit, but I feel like you have a deeper question here, one you haven't quite articulated yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion arises because you are taking an artificially restricted view of the meaning of the phrase 'the number of people in the room'. You are interpreting it as meaning the number of people in the room at a given time, whereas it is also used as a variable, in the same way as as phrases such as 'the speed of the car', or 'the soup of the day' can be used to denote variables. Indeed, the phrase can be used without any intention to denote a specific number, as in 'the number of people in the room was too great to count'.

Comment: Is this other usage strictly logical? The structure is 'the number' of people in 'the room' clearly a number is the subject so why can we describe it as 'changing'? Is it just practical convenience?

Comment: You seem to be asking me the same question over again. I have explained to you that logically the phrase as a whole is used as a label for a variable quantity. That is a common idiomatic use of English. How else do you propose we should express the same idea concisely?